# Something is" a few feet away mind you"

Tags: expressions, idioms

I was watching a Youtube video then I heard this expression ". . . that he, from a few feet away mind you," googled it and I figured out it is quite common. What exactly does it mean?

Comment: Merriam-Webster has: [**mind you**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mind%20you).

Comment: "A few feet away" tells you about distance  and "mind you" is a fixed phrase meaning that you must pay attention or consider what comes next or what has just been said.

Comment: And there should be a comma after "away".

Comment: Why aren't these suggestions included as answers?